Healer uses healing ability to drain his opponent's health
Was this premise in an anime or in an audiobook? The main character was a healer and, during a battle, he used his healing ability to drain the health of his opponent.

Are you thinking of "Redo of Healer"? Not so much drain but afflict injuries - anything he'd previously healed could be inflicted.

In roughly which year did you watch/listen to this?

Is there any possiblity you were thinking of a novel instead of an anime/auidobook?  The reason I ask is there there is a similar premise/scene in Octavia Butler's Patternmaster in which the MC Teray uses his healer ability to actually defeat an opponent.
